# Rails 5 Create, Update and Delete won't work when trying to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying apply CRUD in rails but it didn't save any records for example, I have a model (database table) called Subject and it only has 2 fields (id, title). This is the code when I'm trying to create a record:

```
>> subject = Subject.create(:id => 'Comp1', :title => 'Word Processing')
(0.0ms)  BEGIN
#<Subject id: "Comp1", title: "Word Processing">
(0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
```

the data only saved on an object, but not in the database, here is my code when i am trying to use the new/save

```
>> subject = Subject.new
#<Subject id: nil, title: nil>
>> subject.id = 'Comp1'
"Comp1"
>> subject.title = 'Word Processing'
"Word Processing"
>> >> subject.save
(0.0ms)BEGIN
(0.0ms)ROLLBACK
false
```

I know that when i use the create method it will save automatically in the database, but in my case it wasn't.

when I used subject.errors, this is the result

```
>> subject.errors 
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000006b0d230 @base=#<Subject id: "Comp1", title: "Word Processing">, @messages={:course_group=>["must exist"]}, @details={:course_group=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

maybe it is because the subject_id is a foreign key inside course_group table. All I want is to add data to the subjects table without adding to the course_group table

Comment: try not assigning the `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a validation or a database related issue triggers ROLLBACK. This is indicated by return value `false`.

Try to use `subject.save!` or check `subject.errors` after you called `subject.save`

Comment: subject.errors returns #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000006b0d230 @base=#<Subject id: "Comp1", title: "Word Processing">, @messages={:course_group=>["must exist"]}, @details={:course_group=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

Comment: When your id is not defined as `string` then this is the first issue.  When you post your Subject class I can say more specific things. Now I can only guess that it looks like you have defined a validation for `course_group`. So you have to provide a `course_group` or remove the validation.